# Fab file, unable to remote curl a S3 .gzip file

Tags: python, boto, fabric

Instead of downloading a file on S3 to my local machine, I'm trying to download it to a remote machine in my fabfile. I've got some code with boto that finds the right key, and generates a url (which expires since its private), and then I try to issue something like

```
sudo('curl -o /tmp/test.gz {}'.format(url))
```

This doesn't seem to do anything as nothing is downloaded. I try to download this locally with the above command, but I usually get some relatively small file that isn't right. Do I need different options to the curl command? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of ``curl -v``? You will need to ensure you have a bucket policy on the S3 bucket as well.

Comment: Turns out that wasn't a problem. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just forgot to add quotes around the URL. I added them and it works fine. Final code would be something like:

```
sudo('curl -o /tmp/test.gz "{}"'.format(url))
```